# Change just one position on array Clisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm doing an algorithm that randomizes a TSP (array of citys) based on 1 TSP.

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((= i n-population))
        (setf (aref population i) (shuffle TSP 100))
    )
```

And as far as I know im filling up `i` positions of the array `population` with `(shuffle TSP 100)` that is beeing called each iteration, but the algorithm is setting all array positions and not just i position.

Comment: the problem is that `do` body gets executed on every iteration. If you need to call it exactly once, when `i == n-population`, you could for example put it next to end check: `((= i n-population) (setf ...))` and leave body empty.

Comment: @leetwinski No i want to fill every position with a random array that is beeing randomize on the function shuffle, so the population array have random TSP's, the problem is that the the value of the positions of population array are the same:  iteration 0: population[0] = x, iteration 1: population[0] = y population[1] = y,  iteration 2: population[0] = z population[1] = z population[2] = z

Comment: oh, now i see.. well, i would check your `shuffle` implementation then. are your sure it does return new value every time? could you please show it.

Comment: Yes for debugging im printing the array and shuffle result and for every iteration it changes every position on population array before i.

Comment: what you want exactly `(shuffle TSP 100)` do? If you `(setf (aref population i) sth)` that sth must be just one city - randomly picked isn't it? But it is a picking without putting back. Are you using `alexandria:shuffle`?

Comment: What does `(eq (shuffle TSP 100) (shuffle TSP 100))` tell you?  If not `nil` there's your problem.

Comment: The function that im doing recives the TSP that is an array of cities (a circular path). The pupulation is a array of TSP's. The shuffle function recieves a TSP and mix it, and returns a TSP mixed.

Comment: @tfb as I said before Im printing the value returned by the shuffle each iteration for debugging and it is different. Here it is what i did for debug and the output https://file.io/IYEaWIaO

Comment: Printing the value will not help you in the presence of mutable objects.  You need to understand if the two objects are the same object.  See the two (currently) answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Note.** An earlier version of this answer contained a mistake which would badly alter the statistics of the shuffling: please check below for the corrected version and a note as to what the problem was.]

Given your code, slightly elaborated to turn it into a function:

```
(defun fill-array-with-something (population n-population TSP)
  (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
      ((= i n-population))
    (setf (aref population i) (shuffle TSP 100))))
```

Then each element of `population` from `0` to `(1- n-population)` will be set to the result of `(shuffle TSP 100)`.  There are then two possibilities:

- `(shuffle TSP 100)` returns a fresh object from each call;
- `(shuffle TSP 100)` returns the *same* object – probably `TSP` – from each call.

In the first case, each element of the array will have a distinct value.  In the second case, all elements below `n-population` will have the *same* value.

Without knowing what your `shuffle` function does, here is an example of one which will give the latter behaviour:

```
(defun shuffle (vec n)
  ;; shuffle pairs of elts of VEC, N times.
  (loop with max = (length vec)
        repeat n
        do (rotatef (aref vec (random max))
                    (aref vec (random max)))
        finally (return vec)))
```

And we can test this:

```
> (let ((pop (make-array 10))
         (tsp (vector 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )))
    (fill-array-with-something pop (length pop) tsp)
    pop)
#(#(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6)
  #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6)
  #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6) #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6)
  #(2 8 7 1 3 9 5 4 0 6))
```

As you can see all the elements are mysteriously the same thing, which is because my `shuffle` simply returned its first argument, having modified it in place.

You can check this by either explicitly checking the result of `shuffle`, or by, for instance, using `*print-circle*` to see the sharing.  The latter approach is pretty neat:

```
> (let ((*print-circle* t)
        (pop (make-array 10))
        (tsp (vector 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )))
    (fill-array-with-something pop (length pop) tsp)
    (print pop)
    (values))

#(#1=#(4 6 7 0 1 2 5 9 3 8) #1# #1# #1# #1# #1# #1# #1# #1# #1#)
```

And now it's immediately apparent what the problem is.

The solution is to make sure either that `shuffle` returns a fresh object, or to copy its result.  With my `shuffle` this can be done like this:

```
(defun fill-array-with-something (population n-population tsp)
  (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
      ((= i n-population))
    (setf (aref population i) (shuffle (copy-seq TSP) 100))))
```

**Note** that a previous version of this answer had `(copy-seq (shuffle TSP 100))`: with my version of `shuffle` this is a serious mistake, as it means that the elements in `population` are related to each other but get increasingly shuffled as you go along.  With `(shuffle (copy-seq TSP) 100)` each element gets the same amount of shuffling, independently.

And now

```
> (let ((*print-circle* t)
        (pop (make-array 10))
        (tsp (vector 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )))
    (fill-array-with-something pop (length pop) tsp)
    (print pop)
    (values))

#(#(8 3 4 1 6 9 2 5 0 7) #(8 6 5 1 3 0 4 2 9 7) #(5 0 4 7 1 6 9 3 2 8)
  #(3 0 7 6 2 9 4 5 1 8) #(8 2 5 1 7 3 9 0 4 6) #(0 5 6 3 8 7 2 1 4 9)
  #(4 1 3 7 8 0 5 2 9 6) #(6 9 1 5 0 7 4 2 3 8) #(2 7 5 8 0 9 6 3 4 1)
  #(5 4 8 9 6 7 2 0 1 3))
```

Comment: +1 for a really nice explanation. I would generally prefer using a function that returns a new shuffled vector to one that needs `copy-seq`, but that is probably just a personal hang-up. It is good to have alternatives, in any case ;)

Comment: @exnihilo: thanks.  Unfortunately I realised last night my answer was horribly statistically buggy because I was copying the sequence in the wrong place.  You are right that having a `shuffle` which (a) did not alter its argument and (b) returned a new object would be far better.  So your idea isn't just personal preference: it also would have led to code which was not buggy.

Comment: @miguel__frtt: you might want to look at my amended answer: the original one had a nasty bug.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is in OP function `SHUFFLE` which has not yet been shared; my suspicion is that `SHUFFLE` is shuffling the `*TSP*` array itself in place instead of creating a shuffled copy of that array. The `POPULATION` values are then all referencing the same shuffled `*TSP*` array.

To solve this problem, `SHUFFLE` should return a shuffled array instead of shuffling the array in place. Here is a function that performs a Fisher-Yates shuffle on a vector:

```
(defun shuffle-vector (vect)
  "Takes a vector argument VECT and returns a shuffled vector."
  (let ((result (make-array (length vect) :fill-pointer 0)))
    (labels ((shuffle (v)
               (if (zerop (length v))
                   result
                   (let* ((i (random (length v)))
                          (x (elt v i)))
                     (vector-push x result)
                     (shuffle (concatenate 'vector
                                           (subseq v 0 i)
                                           (subseq v (1+ i))))))))
      (shuffle vect))))
```

Testing in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *TSP* #("Village" "Town" "City" "Metropolis" "Megalopolis"))
*TSP*
CL-USER> (defvar *n-population* 5)
*N-POPULATION*
CL-USER> (defvar *population* (make-array *n-population*))
*POPULATION*
CL-USER> (dotimes (i *n-population*)
           (setf (aref *population* i) (shuffle-vector *TSP*)))

NIL
CL-USER> *population*
#(#("Megalopolis" "City" "Metropolis" "Town" "Village")
  #("Megalopolis" "Metropolis" "Town" "City" "Village")
  #("City" "Megalopolis" "Town" "Village" "Metropolis")
  #("City" "Megalopolis" "Village" "Metropolis" "Town")
  #("Megalopolis" "Town" "Metropolis" "City" "Village"))
```